# Data binding generic variable

Tags: android, generics, android-databinding

How to define a generic type of a data binding variable?

The following code never compiles.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel<Model>"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Follow the [Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain thanks, but there is nothing said about defining generic variable types.

Comment: What is model? I mean this is the type of ViewModel ?

Comment: @DexSebas no, it's a generic parameter of the type ViewModel

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to escape <Model> as shown below:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel&lt;Model>"/>
</data>
```

Android Studio will still show a "Cannot resolve symbol" error, but the XML will compile. It is a known issue. From [Android Studio Support for Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#studio_support):

> Note: Arrays and generic types, such as the Observable class, might display errors when there are no errors.

Comment: i am getting this exception android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find type element for com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel

Comment: i have toolbar i was to create genric listner for it and want to show to include it in all activities

Comment: what if i want to accept any type: com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel<*> etc

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
<data>
<variable
    name="viewModel"
    type="com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel&lt;Model&gt;"/>
</data>
```

`&lt;` is responsible for **<** and `&gt;` is responsible for  **>**.

Comment: does it accept of any type? something like :  com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel<*>

Comment: Yes, it does. You can pass your own object.

Comment: I tried this but with generic types it doesn't compile.

Comment: this worked for me, just ensure to add the Model class as an import, it will work for you

Answer (score 4):

You can set something like examples above:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.path.Model"/>
    <variable
        name="obj"
        type="com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel&lt;Model&gt;"
        />
</data>
```

NOTE: you can write '**>**' or '**`&gt;`**' at end of Model should be OK

To avoid error display do not forget to add line to tell what object type is used:

```
<import type="com.example.path.Model"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a left triangle bracket in XML; XML don't play that way. try

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.viewmodel.ViewModel&lt;Model>"/>
</data>
```