# How to use databinding with generics in an adapter class?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, google-cloud-firestore, android-databinding

I'm trying to use generics in my adapter class. Here is what I have tried:

```
class ItemAdapter<I>(
    options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<I>
): FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<I, ItemAdapter<I>.ItemViewHolder<I>>(options) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder<I> {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val dataBinding = inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(dataBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder<I>, position: Int, item: I) {
        holder.bindItem(item)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder<I>(
        private val dataBinding: ItemDataBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dataBinding.root) {
        fun bindItem(item: I) {
            dataBinding.item = item //Here is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data class="ItemDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.myapp.Item" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{item.name}" />
</layout>
```

I have added that `item` object so I can access the `name` field. However, Android Studio is complaining at this line:

```
dataBinding.item = item
```

With:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Item!
Found: I
```

How can I correctly use generics and get rid of this issue? Thanks

**Edit:**

I don't need to make a particular class generic. I need somehow to cast that `item` object to an object of a particular class. I have tried to add a new property in the class named `classType: Class<I>` and cast ti it using:

```
dataBinding.item = item as classType
```

But without any luck. I have also tried:

```
dataBinding.item = item as I
```

Again with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data binding generic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178955/data-binding-generic-variable)

Comment: @ADM No, because I'm not trying to make the `Item` class generic, I need somehow to make that item object in the layout file somehow generic. That item can become a `Product` object, a `User` object and so on.

Comment: Then your variable type should be of parent type of item not item ..

Comment: @ADM I'm did not understand what you said in the last comment.

Comment: @ADM I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests, that you need to cast the item to type `Item` instead of `I`. This makes sense because your layout declares the variable with type `Item`. The ViewHolder however provides an object of an unconstrained type `I`, which clearly doesn't conform to `Item`.

Instead of a cast, you can constrain the generic type `I` to be a subtype of `Item`:

```
class ItemAdapter<I: Item>(...) {
...
    inner class ItemViewHolder<I: Item>(...) {...}
}
```

This should make the assignment `dataBinding.item = item` valid.

Somewhat unrelated: I think it's unnecessary to redeclare the generic type `I` for the inner class. You should be able to just use the `I` of the outer class `ItemAdapter<I: Item>`.

I have to admit I don't fully understand your code, so I may be missing something. For your reference, here is a very similar implementation of an adapter with data binding I use in my project. It allows configurable layout. The only thing it assumes is a binding variable called `model`.

```
class DataBindingListAdapter<T>(@LayoutRes private val itemLayout: Int, diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>) : ListAdapter<T, DataBindingListAdapter<T>.ViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(layoutInflater, itemLayout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(model: T?) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.model, model)
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi aax! I'm so so so sorry to answer so late. Anyway, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, you are the only one who understood what I'm looking for. However, using `I: Item` not will solve my problem and this is because I simply need `ItemAdapter<I>` because `I` should became `Item`, in another class should become `Product` and so on. Regarding the second part of your answer, yes, it's true I can use the `I` from the outer class. Do you have any other idea on how can I solve this issue? Voted-up.

Comment: I see. What i don't get in your code: Where is the "inflate" method coming from and where do you define which layout file to use?

Comment: What would probably work is to set the binding variable like I did in my example, using the `setVariable` method which is untyped. You only need to name the variable consistently in all the layout files (e.g. `model` instead of `item`/`product`/...).

Comment: ** I have imported it directly `import com.example.my_app.databinding.ItemDataBinding.inflate`. Adding this `<data class="ItemDataBinding">` in my XML file is enough to know which layout is inflated.

Comment: Let me try to use `binding.setVariable(BR.model, model)` as explained in your answer and I get back to you.

Comment: If you use ItemDataBinding, you already have an implicit dependency to the Item type. It will never work to use other layouts or variables. Using `DataBindingUtil` and injecting the layout file ID like I did it is probably also what you need.

Comment: But is `binding.setVariable(BR.model, model)` correct? Shouldn't it be `binding.setVariable(itemLayout, model)`? From your code, is something that I don't understand. If I don't user a specific binding and I use `ViewDataBinding`, what should I add in my XML file? Now I'm using `<data class="ItemDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.myapp.Item" />
    </data>`. How should I change this?

Comment: You need to name the variable in XML accordingly: `<variable name="model"             type="com.example.myapp.Item" />`. `BR` is a generated class which contains all variables from all layout files and maps it to an integer ID (which you need when using `binding.setVariable()`, but this is not the same as the layout file ID).

Comment: I'm almost there. The last thing. When I use `binding.setVariable(BR.model, model)`, it's not working as the model of type `I` does not exist in the BR class. How to solve this last issue?

Comment: The `BR` class itself does not contain any type information. You should see a line like `public static final int model = 1;` in there (the number varies). Try re-building the project if you can't see that. Otherwise: What is the exact error? Is there an exception at runtime? What does it say?

Comment: I tried to rebuild the project and it says: `Unresolved reference: item`. If I open the `BR` class, I see all the other variables that exist in my project but no `item` :(

Comment: Well, did you rename the variable to `model` in XML? Then you should see `BR.model`, not `BR.item`. If you show me more of your current code (maybe in chat) I can help you.

Comment: That was the problem. It really worked man, than you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Generic Adapter class with dataBinding:

```
class BaseAdapter<S>(
    private val mContext: Context?,
    private var list: List<S>?,//generic list can take any Object 
    private val layoutId: Int,// the item_layout 
    private val listener: BaseAdapterListener? =null// call back inside your view
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.DataBindingViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataBindingViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
        return DataBindingViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, layoutId, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list?.size ?: 0
    }

    fun getItem(position: Int):S {
        list?.let {
            if (position < it.size)
                return it[position]
        }
            return list?.get(position) ?: null as S
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataBindingViewHolder, position: Int) {
        listener?.onBind(holder, position)
    }

    interface BaseAdapterListener {
        fun onBind(holder: DataBindingViewHolder, position: Int)
    }

    class DataBindingViewHolder( val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

This is how you can use this inside Fragment:

```
class DemoFragment : Fragment(),BaseAdapter.BaseAdapterListener {
    private var  adapter: BaseAdapter<Audio>?= null// specify your data it taking List<Audio> as parameter
    
    private  lateinit var binding: FragmentPracticeBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
         super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentPracticeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return binding.root;
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        adapter = BaseAdapter(context, arrayListOf(),R.layout.item_audio,this)//created the object of adapter with specific info 
        binding.notesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onBind(holder: BaseAdapter.DataBindingViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder.binding as ItemAudioBinding).apply { 
            // play with your item layout 
        }
        // this nothing but your onBindViewHolder of item_layout type
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this solution does not refer at my problem at all. How can I cast that `item` object to an object of type `I`?

Comment: In My example you can pass any kinda Item object and any kind item layout If You see baseAdapter closly. inside `OnBind(....) { holder.binding}` is type of generic and I'm explicitly casting to my item here---> `holder.binding as ItemAudioBinding` which is casting to layout which i passed at the time of creating baseAdapter

Comment: I'm extending `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<I, ItemAdapter<I>.ItemViewHolder<I>>` and need to do that cast according to the type I use in my adapter.